TPM2-Pytss: Error "hash algorithm not supported or not appropriate" when signing data with TPM2
I am trying to sign data using the TPM2 module in Python 3 with the tpm2-pytss library. The key has already been created and is persistent at handle 0x81000000. The signing process works fine when I use the terminal commands below:
tpm2_createprimary -C e -g sha256 -G ecc -c primary.ctx -a "fixedtpm|fixedparent|sensitivedataorigin|userwithauth|sign"
tpm2_evictcontrol -C o -c primary.ctx 0x81000000 # make the key persistent

echo "data to sign" > data.in.raw # create raw data
sha256sum data.in.raw | awk '{ print "000000 " $1 }' | xxd -r -c 32 > data.in.digest # create digest
tpm2_sign -Q -c 0x81000000 -g sha256 -d -f plain -o data.out.signed data.in.digest

However, when trying to replicate this process in Python with tpm2-pytss, I encounter an error during the signing step. Below is my Python code:
import tpm2_pytss

# Initialize TPM
tpm = tpm2_pytss.ESAPI(tcti=None)
tpm.startup(tpm2_pytss.TPM2_SU.CLEAR)

# Handle for the persistent key
handle = tpm.tr_from_tpmpublic(0x81000000)

# Inspect public key data
public_data, _, _ = tpm.read_public(handle)
public_area = public_data.publicArea
ecc_params = public_area.parameters.eccDetail

print(f"Key Type: {public_area.type}")
print(f"Name Algorithm: {public_area.nameAlg}")
print(f"Attributes: {public_area.objectAttributes}")
print(f"ECC Curve: {ecc_params.curveID}")
print(f"ECC Scheme: {ecc_params.scheme.scheme}")

# Data to be signed
data = b"data to sign"

# Generate digest and validation ticket
digest, validation = tpm.hash(
    data,
    hash_alg=tpm2_pytss.TPM2_ALG.SHA256,
    hierarchy=tpm2_pytss.ESYS_TR.NULL
)

# Set up ECDSA signing scheme
signing_scheme = tpm2_pytss.TPMT_SIG_SCHEME(
    scheme=tpm2_pytss.TPM2_ALG.ECDSA,
    details=tpm2_pytss.TPMU_SIG_SCHEME()  # Empty scheme for ECDSA
)

# Attempt to sign the digest using TPM
try:
    signature = tpm.sign(
        handle,         # Key handle in TPM
        digest,         # Generated digest
        in_scheme=signing_scheme,  # ECDSA signing scheme
        validation=validation  # Validation ticket
    )
    print(f"Generated Signature: {signature}")
except tpm2_pytss.TSS2_Exception as e:
    print(f"Error while signing: {e}")

When I run this, I get the following output and error:
Key Type: ecc
Name Algorithm: sha256
Attributes: fixedtpm|fixedparent|sensitivedataorigin|userwithauth|sign
ECC Curve: nist_p256
ECC Scheme: null
WARNING:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_Sign.c:314:Esys_Sign_Finish() Received TPM Error 
ERROR:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_Sign.c:108:Esys_Sign() Esys Finish ErrorCode (0x000002c3) 
Error while signing: tpm:parameter(2):hash algorithm not supported or not appropriate

What I've tried:
I verified the key attributes and scheme using tpm.read_public(). The scheme shows as null, which might be the issue.
I've used the terminal commands to confirm the key works correctly for signing.
Adjusted the signing scheme in Python to match the expected ECDSA parameters.

Questions:
How can I correctly specify the signing scheme for the TPM2_ALG.ECDSA key in tpm2-pytss?
Is there an issue with how I am setting up the digest or validation ticket?
Should the key's scheme (null) be explicitly set during creation to support ECDSA?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here’s how I resolved the issue and successfully generated a signature using the tpm2-pytss library. I used this example script as a reference:
from tpm2_pytss import ESAPI, TPM2_SU, TPMT_SIG_SCHEME, TPM2_ALG, TPMT_TK_HASHCHECK, TPM2_ST, TPM2_RH, ESYS_TR, TPM2B_DIGEST
import secrets

ectx = ESAPI(tcti=None)
ectx.startup(TPM2_SU.CLEAR)

handle1 = ectx.tr_from_tpmpublic(0x81000000)

# Define the signing scheme for ECDSA with SHA256
scheme = TPMT_SIG_SCHEME(scheme=TPM2_ALG.ECDSA)
scheme.details.any.hashAlg = TPM2_ALG.SHA256

# Create the validation for hash check
validation = TPMT_TK_HASHCHECK(tag=TPM2_ST.HASHCHECK, hierarchy=TPM2_RH.OWNER)

# Generate some random data to sign
segredo = secrets.token_hex(16)

# Generate the digest and ticket for the hash of the data
digest, ticket = ectx.hash(segredo.encode(), TPM2_ALG.SHA256, ESYS_TR.OWNER)

# Sign the digest using the defined scheme and validation
s1 = ectx.sign(handle1, TPM2B_DIGEST(digest), scheme, validation)

print(f"Generated Signature: {s1}")


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
